# C, HTML and CGI

Tags: html, c, cgi

I have a functionality written in C. I have to give input through the html page and the operation to be processed in C (on submit of a button) and the result has to be given to the same html page.

Please help me out by given some simple examples.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html). You will (of course) need admin access to the web server where you wish to access your program.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to have admin access to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to give input through the html
>   page and the operation to be processed
>   in C (on submit of a button) and the
>   result has to be given to the same
>   html page.

It looks like you need to make an Ajax program in C.

Simplest example of CGI programming in C:

```
int main ()
{
     printf ("Content-Type: text/plain\n\nHello world\n");
}
```

The C bit is actually quite easy, the Ajax bit is more involved.